# Kivy TreeView with checkbox and editable text

Tags: python, treeview, kivy

How to add to Kivy TreeView a checkbox and editable text to each child.

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: I didn't. Im new on kivy, just have the example from documentation

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html) for the `TreeView` touches on how to do that, but doesn't provide much detail. Here is a way to do that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode


class MyNode(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop('text', 'None')
        super(MyNode, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        # make height reasonable
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = dp(25)

        # make the parts of the node
        self.lbl = Label(text=text, size_hint_x=0.2)
        self.chkbx = CheckBox(size_hint_x=0.1, color=(1, 1, 1, 3.5))  # alpha=3.5 to make it more visible
        self.txtinpt = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=15, padding=[6, 3, 6, 0])

        # add the parts to the BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)
        self.add_widget(self.chkbx)
        self.add_widget(self.txtinpt)


class MyTreeNode(MyNode, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class MyTreeView(TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__()
        self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text='node 1'))
        node2 = self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text='node 2'))
        self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text='node 3'), node2)
        self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text='node 4'), node2)


class TreeViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyTreeView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TreeViewApp().run()
```

Comment: Great idea to enhance the alpha of the CheckBox.  I would never have thought of that.  It helped me alot.  Thanks.